# Loop inside IF and Run the macro with protcted sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to make invoice using Excel VBA. And what I did first is making an (Next Invoice) Function,
which I did using IF statement as shown, but the problem is that I want to loop this function every time I click on the button.
here is the code I used:

```vb
Sub NextAWB()
If IsEmpty(Range("C6,C8,C11,C13,D24,J27,B27,E27,C27,F27").Value) = True Then
   MsgBox "AWB Is Empty !"
ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("C6,C8,C11,C13,D24,J27,B27,E27,C27,F27").Value) = False Then
   Range("G3").Value = Range("G3").Value + 1
   Range("C6,C8,C11,C13,D24,J27,B27,E27,C27,F27").Value = ""
End If
   
End Sub
```

Another issue I faced that I can not run this macro on protected sheet. Is there any idea to bypass this issue?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks

For the first bit I could not figure out how to deal with it to be honest.

For the other issue I tried (Me.Protect UserInterfaceOnly := True) but no luck.

Comment: Before applying `UserInterfaceOnly := True`, you have to remove the existing protection. Also, if you save the workbook, it removes the setting so you need to reapply it.

Comment: Please don't poast images of code - it makes it much harder for anyone to help you, since they may need to start by retyping it. Your `IsEmpty()` test doesn't work.  Better to use something like `Application.CountA(rangeHere)`